# react-testing-library shows element in debug but fails test

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a test that the 'debug' is showing the element exists, but fails the test.
Its possible that the link is further down the page and css wise, is hidden from view, but how to set react-testing-library to know what are the 'dimensions' of the total viewport?

**example react output**

```
<h3>I am a title</h3>
<p>I contain a child link: <a href={'somepath'}>some link</a> and some text</p>
```

**exmaple test**

```
 it('should render form content', () => {
    const { queryByText, debug } = render(<MyComponenet />);
    expect(queryByText('I am title')).toBeInTheDocument(); // This passes
    debug(); // This shows the element exists with the text.
    expect(queryByText('I contain a child link')).toBeInTheDocument(); // This fails
});
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i discovered that getByText or queryByText is an 'exact' match, so it won't test partial text. I need to add:

```
queryByText('I contain a child link', {exact: false})
```

Comment: You can avoid this by not using random strings, but puting your strings in constants, which you can export and then use in your tests. That way they are always identical.

Comment: @Mister_CK yeah I agree. I just named it this way for the test purpose to be obvious. Its not the actual text in my use case.